# What does 'merge branch xxx' mean?

Tags: git, github, version

I see this kind of log in log history, I know `merge branch xx into xx`.But what does `merge branch xxx` mean?

Comment: This question is really unclear. Add screenshots or actual examples. Also commit messages can be chosen freely so it's possible that people just write those kind of messages manually.

Answer (score 0):

Merge branch will merge a branch on to your branch.
Eg. You have a branch X which is your master branch and branch Y which is your developer branch in GIT repository. So, now X is n commits ahead of Y. Now, you want that Y should be in sync with x. Merge branch will take the code from X as well as changes in Y that are already there and then it will commit those changes into Y. Now, your branch is in sync or may be ahead of X.

Comment: I think the question is about commit messages containing `merge branch development` rather than the git command `git merge development`.

Answer (score 0):

Git shortens `merge branch xx into yy` to just `merge branch xx` where `yy` is `master`.

Every branch sooner or later must be merged into master, there is no need to write `merge branch xx into master`. (-:

Answer (score -1):

```
merge branch xx
```

It would simply merge your current branch/working branch with the branch you want to merge it.

Comment: I think the question is about commit messages containing `merge branch development` rather than the git command `git merge development`.

Comment: I am sorry, completely overlooked it.